# Type 'Ref<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLLIElement> | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use the following component to create tabs within my project.

```
   function Tab({
      children,
      className,
      fullWidth = true,
      ...props
    }: ExtractProps<typeof HeadlessTab> & {
      fullWidth?: boolean;
    }) {
      const list = useContext(listContext);
      const liRef = React.createRef<HTMLLIElement>()
      return (
        <HeadlessTab as={Fragment}>
        {({ selected }) => (
          <li
          ref={liRef}
            className={twMerge([
              "focus-visible:outline-none",
              fullWidth && "flex-1",
              list.variant == "tabs" && "-mb-px",
            ])}
            {...props}
          >
            <tabContext.Provider
              value={{
                selected: selected,
              }}
            >
              {typeof children === "function"
                ? children({
                    selected: selected,
                  })
                : children}
            </tabContext.Provider>
          </li>
        )}
      </HeadlessTab>
      );
    }
```

However, I get the following error whenever I try to run the project. I have tried a couple of things such as re-casting the ref to HTMLLIElement while assigning it to the

element:

```
    TS2322: Type 'Ref<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLLIElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLLIElement> | undefined'.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLLIElement>'.
      Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLLIElement': type, value
    32 |     {({ selected }) => (
    33 |       <li
  > 34 |       ref={liRef}
       |       ^^^
    35 |         className={twMerge([
    36 |           "focus-visible:outline-none",
    37 |           fullWidth && "flex-1",
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong with this.

Comment: For functional components you should use [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

import useRef from "react" and replace

"const liRef = React.createRef()"

with the snippet below.

This should help with the type error your getting related to the ref attribute

```js
const liRef = useRef<HTMLLIElement>(null);
```